# Can we use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet with [HttpPost] attribute?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Since sometimes my system hits with `GET` type and some times hit with `POST` type.
While returning Json result shall I use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` if I decorate my method with `[HttpPost]` attribute?

eg:

```
        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, Authorize]
        public ActionResult AssociatedDevices(long id, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var dataParameters = request.ToDataParameters();
            var deviceSetLogic = new DeviceSetLogic();
            var associatedDevices = deviceSetLogic.GetAssociatedDevicesByDeviceSetId(id, dataParameters);

            var result = new DataSourceResult()
            {
                Data = associatedDevices,
                Total = Convert.ToInt32(dataParameters.TotalRecordCount)
            };

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

If I write like above in PROD environment will it cause any issues? Please advise.

Comment: If your method is decorated with `HttpPost` attribute, you do not need to use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` .Why don't you test it locally before shipping to PROD?

Comment: since, in prod environment we are getting an exceptions like 
'System.Web.HttpException
A public action method 'AssociatedDevices' was not found on controller 'AdminSite.Web.Controllers.EntitlementsSearchController'.'

But we are unable to reproduce this error in localhost. Somewhere the system is hitting GET type instead of POST which causes this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` parameter to your return Json has no use since your method is decorated with `[HttpPost]` so it can't be called using the GET verb.

You say that sometimes your system "hits with get and sometimes with post" but if you try to call this method using a GET request the routing system will most likely get a 404.

There is no way this method answers a GET request, so adding the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` only makes the code less clear.

If your action must be reachabe using POST and GET verbs, it should be decorated with `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get)]` or `[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]`

Comment: Ok, so if I decorate with AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get|HttpVerbs.Post)] then can I use this JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet in Json result?

Comment: i have updated my answer. To answer your comment : yes

Comment: Thank you for your upvote. If your question is answered, please mark it as such.